# How to change expression used to determine symbology of feature-linked annotation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, annotation

I created and adjusted a large feature-linked annotation feature class in ArcMap and realize that I symbolized the annotation classes based on an incorrect field. Is there a way to change the symbology expression so that I don't have to regenerate and move hundreds of annotations?

Comment: The 'SQL QUERY' dialog was greyed out on the annotation classes property tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in ArcCatalog, **but you cannot have the feature class open in ArcMap**. For whatever reason, some parameters are editable while the feature is open in ArcMap, while editing of other parameters is disabled.

To change the symbology expression on the annotation classes, go to the feature classes properties>annotation classes tab, and choose SQL QUERY... to create your symbology class definitions.

[image: anotation class dialog]

To initiate an update of the annotation feature class, you will need to field calculate the field in question on the parent feature class using field=field. More info here: http://support.esri.com/EM/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30790